# should i install bumblebee?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, bumblebee

My laptop has dual graphics

- Intel Graphics 4000
- Nvidia geforce 630m

when i run this command in the terminal:

```
    sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

I get the following output:

```
   0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
   1:DIS: :Pwr:0000:01:00.0
```

I read that (+) means that only Integrated Graphics Card is powered ON.

Now my question is that, should i install BUMBLEBEE? The doubt is because, my battery shows 2hrs only (Fully charged). But, it can stand for about 4hrs (fully charged) in windows.

Give me suggestion on whether to install BUMBLEBEE or not. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` means that the Intel graphics card is being used. Your Nvidia graphics card is still powered on (see `Pwr`, if it was off, then it reads `Off`).

By installing Bumblebee, it will power off the Nvidia graphics card and thereby extending your battery life. You can optionally run programs on the nvidia graphics card using the `optirun` program.

By not installing Bumblebee, you will have an ineffective heater which may be useful in the winter.

Comment: Quick reply! And is there any ways to automatically use my nvidia card when using graphic intense apps?

Comment: @dinesh2707 Nope, you have to that manually. bumblebee-ui was a program that allows you to edit the launchers, making programs start with `optirun`, but I haven't visited it for a while. To be honest, my Nvidia card is mostly off these days, I only used it when I had to run certain OpenGL programs for University projects.